# Where in the torah is, "You people are Elohim”?

Tags: john, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible

In the Christian bible, in [John 10:34](http://www.biblestudytools.com/parallel-bible/passage/?q=john%2010:31-39&t=cjb&t2=bbe) Yeshua is quoted:

> In answer, Yeshua said,
>   "Is there not a saying in your Torah,
>   I have said, 'You people are Elohim [the gods]'"?

What is the chapter and verse Yeshua refers to,
or what is the context?

Comment: [John 10:31-39 on Biblegateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+10%3A31-39&version=NIV) has a footnote that says the reference is to [Psalm 82](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+82&version=NIV):6.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase in question is not in the Torah proper, but from [Psalm 82](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16303#showrashi=true), as the comment says. Elohim has many meanings in Tanach, from one of the Divine Names to "judges","rulers","godlike beings"(JPS translation of 82:6) or as Chabad has, "angelic beings". Chabad also translates "b'nei Elyon" as "angels of the Most High", instead of the more common "sons of the Most High".

Comment: bnei means sons.